# jqgrid not working in IE8 and firefox 3.6.6

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

My jqgrid is working in Firefox 7 and IE9 but not in IE8 or Firefox 3.6.6. I am using latest version of jqgrid.

Here are the script files I've included:

```
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui.multiselect.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui/minified/jquery.ui.widget.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui/minified/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is my script in case if it's needed:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#jobs').jqGrid({
            url: '/SearchJob/Jobs/',
            postData: {
                'JobTitle': function () { return $('#JobTitle').val(); },
                'City': function () { return $('#City').val(); },
                'SelectJobType': function () { return $('#SelectJobType option:selected').val(); },
                'SalaryStartRange': function () { return $('#SalaryStartRange').val(); },
                'SalaryEndRange': function () { return $('#SalaryEndRange').val(); },
                'SelectCategory': function () { return $('#SelectCategory option:selected').val(); },
                'SelectIndustry': function () { return $('#SelectIndustry option:selected').val(); },
                'CompanyName': function () { return $('#CompanyName').val(); },
                'Keywords': function () { return $('#Keywords').val(); },
                'SelectSalaryType': function () { return $('#SelectSalaryType option:selected').val(); }
            },
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Title', 'Category', 'Company Name', 'Location', 'Salary Range', 'Date Posted'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Title', index: 'title', width: 150, align: 'left', formatter: 'showlink', formatter: linkformatter },
                { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 150, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'CompanyName', index: 'CompanyName', width: 150, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'CombinedLocation', index: 'CombinedLocation', width: 150, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'salaryRange', index: 'salaryRange', width: 150, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'DatePosted', index: 'DatePosted', width: 150, align: 'center' },
            ],
            shrinkToFit: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            loadonce: false,
            pager: jQuery('#jobPager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'jobid',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '',
            caption: 'Jobs',
            width: '100%',
            height: "100%"
        });
        $('#search').click(function () {
            $('#jobs').trigger('reloadGrid');
            return false;
        });



    });

    linkformatter = function (cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
        console.log(rowObject);
        return "<a href='@Url.Action("JobView", "RecruiterProfile")/" + rowObject[rowObject.length - 1] +  "'>" + cellValue + "<a/>"; 
    }
```

Attached is the error that I get in IE8 and Firefox 3.6:

Removing screenshots because I am not allowed to post. If anybody drops here in future the error was of console. Removed in from my formatter function and it worked!

**Update**: The error only comes in Firefox 3.6 if I have disabled Firebug. I enable Firebug and everything works as expected. What am I doing wrong? Am I including the wrong script files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should write..

```
window.console.log(rowObject);
```

In place of

```
console.log(rowObject);
```

or you might get answer from here....

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?575320-how-not-to-let-console.log%28%29-to-cause-error-on-IE-or-other-browsers

Comment: Okkkk.. Fine since you are the 1st one who solved my issue. I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 console.log(rowObject);
```

in IE8 or Firefox 3.6.6,It does not console object.It's will be working when you remove this.

Answer (score 1):

You answerd almost yourself on your question in the last "Update" part: You have to test

```
if (window.console) {
    window.console.log(rowObject);
}
```

or

```
if (console) {
    console.log(rowObject);
}
```

because `console` is not always exist.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Actually it was running on localhost but error came in client's browser :p.